# Connecting phrases with the stem of masu-form

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

When is it possible to connect sentences using the stem of masu-form? Are there restrictions on the use of this form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [なく vs. なくて and stem form vs. てform as conjunctions](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f-vs-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6-and-stem-form-vs-%e3%81%a6form-as-conjunctions)

Answer (score 2):

You can list activities. It does not imply temporal order, so it is sometimes unnatural. When the verb stem ends with a consonant, you need to insert the epenthetic vowel i.

> 野菜を買い、切り、炒めた。

If you want to imply temporal order, use the te form.

> 野菜を買って、切って、炒めた。

Comment: Is there any time when it would be preferable to use over the connective って? (e.g. does it carry a different nuance, is it more conversational, etc.)

Comment: Another answerer said the て-form implied order and 中止系 did not, but changed their answer and said neither actually imply order. They said the form which means one action came after another is てから. 
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/%e3%81%a6-versus-combining-form-for-joining-clauses