# What does どおし mean in this song?

Tags: syntax, hiragana, song-lyrics, compound-verbs

In the song Chercher by Kotoko there's the line

> 心配性｛しんぱいしょう｝と言｛い｝われても　ハラハラのしどおしよ

And in a subtitled video it gets translated to: "Even if you say I'm a worrier, you're anxious with me"

It all makes sense expect that どおし part...
Is it supposed to be 同士｛どうし} ? But if so, how come it's written with a different spelling that my IME doesn't acknowledge?

I tried researching this and the best I found is this https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1216623117 
but I don't know. Does anyone know what this どおし is supposed to be and why it gets spelt this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is from the verb 「通{とお}す」.

> 「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) + 通す」

means:

> "to continue [verb]-ing to the end"

In 「しどおし」, the first 「し」 is the 連用形 of the verb 「する」.  「どおし」is the 連用形 of 「通す」.  The と-to-ど change is [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku).

Thus, 「どおし」 has nothing to do with「同士」 -- none.

「通す」 is written 「とおす」 in kana, not 「とうす」.

My TL of the line:

> "Even if they call me a natural worrier, I just can't stop feeling uneasy!"

Other examples:

「朝まで飲み通す」 = "to keep on drinking till the dawn"

「９回まで投げ通す」 = "to continue to pitch till the 9th inning"

「仕事をやり通す」 = "to completely finish one's work"

Comment: huh, alright thank you

Comment: I think the reason for the rendaku is that -どおし is a different pattern than -とおす.

Comment: Actually could you help me understand how to parse that phrase lol? The の in のしどおし doesn't make sense to me and is the しよ at the end like ending it with してよ？

Comment: 「しどおし」 is a noun here though it is made of two verbs originally.  連用形 often functions as a noun as well.  ハラハラ is also used as a noun here though it is originally an onomatopoeia.  So, we have 「Noun + の + Noun + sentence-ender よ」, which should make perfect sense unless you are a beginner.   Look at the recent question here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73236/nominalizing-verb-with-%e3%81%84-ending-vs-%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ae and you will find that 泳ぎ (連用形 of the verb 泳ぐ) is used as a noun.  The use of onomatopoeias as nouns is a common phenomenon in informal speech.  (continued)

Comment: We say things like ドキドキが止まらない, このワクワクはあなたのせいよ！, etc.

Comment: If you are still "seeing" してよ or しよ at the end after reading my answer, I probably failed completely.  I am outta here.

Comment: no your answer makes sense lol, thank you!