# adding ーすませ to the end of a noun

Tags: grammar

The second line of the song Umi no Koe/海の声 says:

> 風の声に　耳すませ
>   (kaze no koe ni mimisumase)

In this sentence, what does it mean when すませ　is added at the end of 耳/ear.

The full verse is this:

> 空の声が 聴きたくて
>   風の声に ***耳すませ***
>   海の声が 知りたくて
>   君の声を 探してる

Thank you!

Comment: 梅の声 is read as ume no koe, but judging by the rest of your post, it just looks like a typo (first line)  As for understanding this, I might suggest this: http://jisho.org/word/%E6%BE%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99

Answer (score 3):

Here, 澄ませ【すませ】 is a verb. The object marker を after 耳 has been omitted. (Dropping を makes this part 5 morae long and rhyme with the other lines.)

済ませ is the masu-stem (aka pre-masu form, 連用形) of the causative form of the godan (aka consonant-stem or U-) intransitive verb 澄む.

- [**澄む**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120157/meaning/m0u/%E6%BE%84%E3%82%80/): an intransitive godan verb, "to be/become clean/clear/transparent/keen"
- **澄ませる**: the causative form of 澄む, "to make something clean/clear/keen". see the conjugation rule [here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-causative-form/).
- **耳を澄ませる**: (literally "to make the ears keen") "to listen carefully"
- **耳を澄ませ**: the masu-stem (pre-masu form) of 耳を澄ませる

The masu-stem can be used to continue a sentence just like the te-form. (See: [て versus combining-form for joining clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23789/5010) ) Therefore, the line means "I listen carefully to the voice of wind (, and ...)"

---

Well, in fact, 澄ませる is an uncommon form, because we have a standalone transitive version of 澄む, namely 澄ます, which is also a godan verb.

- [**澄ます**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/119957/meaning/m0u/): a transitive godan verb, "to make something clean/clear/keen"
- **耳を澄ます**: (literally "to make the ears keen") "to listen carefully"
- **耳を澄まし**: the masu-stem of 耳を澄ます

I think 耳を澄ます is worth memorizing as an idiom, and is far more common than 耳を澄ませる. But they mean the same thing, anyway.

All in all, the following four forms will work quite similarly in this context.

- **耳を澄まして**: the te-form of 澄ます
- **耳を澄まし**: the masu-stem of 澄ます
- **耳を澄ませて**: the te-form of the causative form of 澄む (relatively uncommon)
- **耳を澄ませ**: the masu-stem of the causative form of 澄む (least common among the four)

Answer (score 0):

> 空の声が 聴きたくて
> 風の声に 耳**すませ**
> 海の声が 知りたくて
> 君の声を 探してる

Given phrases are parts of the [lyrics](http://utaten.com/lyric/%E6%B5%A6%E5%B3%B6%E5%A4%AA%E9%83%8E%28%E6%A1%90%E8%B0%B7%E5%81%A5%E5%A4%AA%29/%E6%B5%B7%E3%81%AE%E5%A3%B0/) of a song "海｛うみ｝の声｛こえ｝", but quite a few phrases are omitted. Complementing the omitted parts taking the whole context of the lyrics into account will be as follows:

空＜から聞こえそうな君＞の声が 聞きたくて
＜空を駆け抜ける＞風の<del>声</del>＜音＞に 耳＜を＞すませ＜て＞
＜君の声を 探している＞

海＜から聞こえそうな君＞の声が 知りたくて
＜波の音に 耳をすませて＞
君の声を 探して＜い＞る

> 空から聞こえそうな君の声が 聞きたくて
> 空を駆{か}け抜｛ぬ｝ける風の音に 耳を**すませて**
> 君の声を 探している
>
> 海から聞こえそうな君の声が 知りたくて
> 波｛なみ｝の音｛おと｝に 耳を**すませて**
> 君の声を 探している

**すませ** is a part of the phrase "風の音に/波の音に 耳をすませて君の声を探している *I'm listening carefully to the sound of the wind/waves in order to catch your voice*", which becomes "澄ませ" when written including *kanji*.

---

### EDIT:

どうしてこのような解釈｛かいしゃく｝ができるかを解説｛かいせつ｝します。
この解説は日本語学習者の中で上級者を対象｛たいしょう｝としますので、日本語で書きます。

解説にあたって歌詞｛かし｝の全文が必要｛ひつよう｝になりますので、以下に引用｛いんよう｝して掲載｛けいさい｝します。

海の声

作詞：篠原誠    作曲：BEGIN

**空の声が 聴きたくて**
**風の声に 耳すませ**
**海の声が 知りたくて**
**君の声を 探してる**

会えない そう思うほどに
会いたいが 大きくなってゆく
**川のつぶやき 山のささやき**
**君の声のように 感じるんだ**

目を閉じれば 聞こえてくる
君のコロコロした 笑い声
声に出せば 届きそうで 今日も 歌ってる
海の声にのせて

空の声が 聴きたくて
風の声に 耳すませ
海の声が 知りたくて
君の声を 探してる

たとえ僕が おじいさんになっても
ここで 歌ってる
君だけを想って

海の声よ 風の声よ
空の声よ 太陽の声よ
川の声よ 山の声よ
**僕の声を 乗せてゆけ**

まず、歌詞｛かし｝の全体｛ぜんたい｝を読｛よ｝むと、この歌｛うた｝を歌う人（「私」でも良いが、この説明｛せつめい｝では仮｛かり｝に「作者｛さくしゃ｝」とする）が、今は会｛あ｝えない恋人｛こいびと｝である「君｛きみ｝」を慕｛した｝った歌｛うた｝であることが分｛わ｝かる。

次に、直接｛ちょくせつ｝「君」に会えなくても、作者は君の声だけでも聞｛き｝きたいことが分かる。

「川のつぶやき」や「山のささやき」を、「君の声のように 感じるんだ」という歌詞から、この作者は「川の水の流れる音」や「山で聞こえる音」を人の話す声のように想像｛そうぞう｝して聞いていることが分かる。「山の音」とは、山そのものには実際｛じっさい｝に音がないので、山に生｛は｝えている木々｛きぎ｝が風｛かぜ｝で互｛たが｝いに擦｛す｝れて発｛はっ｝する音｛おと｝や、樹木｛じゅもく｝の間｛あいだ｝を吹｛ふ｝き抜｛ぬ｝ける時｛とき｝に発する音を意味していると思う。従｛したが｝って、歌詞全体を通｛つう｝じて、「君の声」以外｛いがい｝で使｛つか｝われている「声」、「つぶやき」や「ささやき」などは、「人間の声」ではなく、「音」という意味で解釈｛かいしゃく｝することが自然｛しぜん｝である。

この歌詞には、「空」「風」「海」「川」「山」「太陽｛たいよう｝」という自然物｛しぜんぶつ｝がたくさん登場｛とうじょう｝するが、「風」と「川」以外｛いがい｝は直接｛ちょくせつ｝「音」が出｛だ｝ないので、「空の音」「海の音」は、「空」や「海」の辺｛あた｝りに存在｛そんざい｝する実際｛じっさい｝に音が出るものを通じて出る音と解釈するのが妥当｛だとう｝である。すなわち、「山のささやき」→「山の音」→「山に生えている木々が風で互いに擦れて発する音や樹木の間を吹き抜ける時に発する音」と解釈した方法と同じである。

話は若干｛じゃっかん｝脱線｛だっせん｝するが、「風の声→風の音」と解釈するとしたが、「風の音に乗｛の｝せた君の声」「風の音に託｛たく｝した君の声」「風の音に託された君の声」という解釈も十分あり得る。歌詞の最後に「僕の声を 乗せてゆけ」という表現｛ひょうげん｝がある。日本語の用法｛ようほう｝で、「～に声を乗せる」「～に思｛おも｝いを乗せる」という表現｛ひょうげん｝がある。例えば、「電波｛でんぱ｝に音楽｛おんがく｝を乗せる」や「搬送波｛はんそうは｝に実際の音声｛おんせい｝信号｛しんごう｝を乗せる」のように「実際の信号」とその信号を送る媒体｛ばいたい｝である「搬送波」の関係としてこの作詞家｛さくしか｝が言葉｛ことば｝を使｛つか｝っているように思｛おも｝う。これを「僕の声を 乗せてゆけ」にあてはめると、「風の音に僕の声を 乗せてゆけ」となる。従って、「風の声」を「風の音に乗った君の声」と解釈することも可能であるが、話が複雑になるので、ここでは、「風の声＝風の音」と理解することにする。

話は戻｛もど｝って、質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝の提示｛ていじ｝した４行の歌詞に着目｛ちゃくもく｝すると、１行目｛ぎょうめ｝、２行目と最後｛さいご｝の４行目が一まとまりの文章｛ぶんしょう｝になることが分かる。また、３行目と４行目とで別の一まとまりの文章になる。その意味｛いみ｝で「君の声を 探してる」という４行目は両方｛りょうほう｝の文章｛ぶんしょう｝から使｛つか｝われている。４行目の歌詞を１、２行目の続｛つづ｝きに置｛お｝かなかったのは、歌詞がくどくなるのを防｛ふせ｝ぐためだと思われる。

１行目、２行目と最後の４行目からなる一まとまりの文章である「空の声が 聴きたくて　風の声に 耳（を）すませ（て）　君の声を 探して（い）る」は、「風に乗っているであろうどうしても聞きたい君の声を探して耳を澄ませて風の音を聴（/聞）いている」という意味であろう。「空の声」は前に説明した「空を吹く風の音」であり、「君が空に向｛む｝かって発｛はっ｝した声」かもしれない。

３行目と４行目の一まとまりの文章を見ると、「海の声」という行は、１つ目のまとまりのある文章にある「空の声」の行と文の形｛かたち｝が同｛おな｝じであり、「海の声」も「空の声」も実際には音を出さない自然物である点からも、同じ役割｛やくわり｝として呼応｛こおう｝関係｛かんけい｝があることが分かる。すると、「空の声」を実際に担｛にな｝う役目｛やくめ｝である音を発する「風の声」に相当｛そうとう｝する部分が「海の声」には無｛な｝いことが分かる。「風の声に 耳すませ」から類推｛るいすい｝すると、自｛おの｝ずと「波｛なみ｝の声に 耳をすませ」が省略されていることが分かる。　これは敢｛あ｝えて省略｛しょうりゃく｝する必要はなく、あった方が自然な日本語であるが、歌詞の全体を４行詩｛ぎょうし｝の組｛く｝み合｛あ｝わせで成｛な｝り立｛た｝たせるために、また、読者｛どくしゃ｝が補｛おぎな｝うことが可能｛かのう｝だと判断｛はんだん｝して省略したものと思われる。