# Stem of ます-form as conjuction

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, renyōkei

おはよう！

I came up with the stem of the ます-form while trying to read a book. I already checked the questions [Connecting phrases with the stem of masu-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/connecting-phrases-with-the-stem-of-masu-form) and [なく vs. なくて and stem form vs. てform as conjunctions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F-vs-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6-and-stem-form-vs-%E3%81%A6form-as-conjunctions). So, from those I learned that it is like て-form except that it doesn't imply temporal order.

Now, as far as I know (which is not much yet...), the 〜たり、〜たりする form does the same thing, which is similar to using や to list nouns and imply that there may be others, and does not imply temporal order.

```
Example:
(1) 今朝{けさ}起{お}きて、シャワーを浴{あ}びて、朝{あさ}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べました。
(2) 今朝{けさ}起{お}きたり、シャワーを浴{あ}びたり、朝{あさ}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べたりしました。
(3) 今朝{けさ}起{お}き、シャワーを浴{あ}び、朝{あさ}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べました。
```

Could someone please explain the difference between the 〜たり and the stem of the ます-form when used as conjuction?

Comment: (3) is the same as (1).

Comment: @user4092: But in the questions I referenced it is said that (1) has temporal order, while (3) has not.

Comment: Soon, you'll run into the likes of (3) that has temporal order as long as you keep learning Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

たり is used to mean 'do things such as ...' e.g.

> ケーキをたべたり、ビールを飲んだりします。
>
> I do things like eat cake and drink beer.

It is a non-exhaustive list of things that the person does.

On the other hand the pre-masu/combining form of the verb is just a more formal version of the て form and is used more often in writing than in speech. It can usually be translated to mean 'and' when joining two clauses.