# Is the 「て」 missing from 「され」 in this sentence?

Tags: syntax, て-form, renyōkei

Here is the sentence.

> ソフトのプレイ中にHOMEボタンを押すと、ソフトが**中断され**HOMEメニューが表示されます。

I think 「て」 should follow the verb 「中断され」 to create conjunctive/continuative form.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not. This れ is the pre-masu-form (stem) of れる, and it doesn't require て after it.

- [なく vs. なくて and stem form vs. てform as conjunctions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2934/5010)
- [Connecting phrases with the stem of masu-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6412/5010)
- [Stem of ます-form as conjuction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25921/5010)
- [て versus combining-form for joining clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23789/5010)

In your example, you can insert て after 中断され without changing the meaning of the sentence. But since this is from a formal documentation, doing so may make the sentence look a little less sophisticated.