# What is the difference between もとづいて and もとづき

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

What is the difference between both of them? I could not find any explanations so I came here.

Comment: Do you have examples in which you found these?  Mostly this is a literary difference, but not entirely.  Examples of where you found these usages will help us better answer you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you could not find any explanation specifically about them is because the difference can be explained as a generic difference between a te-form and a masu-stem:

- [なく vs. なくて and stem form vs. てform as conjunctions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2934/5010)
- [Connecting phrases with the stem of masu-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6412/5010)
- [Stem of ます-form as conjuction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25921/5010)
- [て versus combining-form for joining clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23789/5010)
- [Is there a term for using conjugating verbs such that the sentence continues with another clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/5010)

Since もとづく is already a stiff verb, the difference between もとづいて and もとづき is small, and they are interchangeable. Still, もとづき sounds relatively a little stiffer or more academic.

Comment: Thanks for the short and helpful answer.