# The use of し in this sentence

Tags: renyōkei

I'm using manga to learn some grammar and the following sentence came up.

> オレは旅をし世界をめぐっていると…

I can't figure out why し is being used. I know it can be used for listing and such, but being next to を particle confuses me.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/connecting-phrases-with-the-stem-of-masu-form

Comment: Those examples show し as the continue form of verb~ます. In my example, 旅をし does not look it is case. Maybe し is a verb by itself?

Comment: し is the ます-stem form of する.