# what is the role of "立ち" in below sentence?

Tags: particle-に

I know the total meaning of this sentence:

> 黒田君達 特Sが上に立ち望月君達が それを下から支える役回りというわけなんです。

but I want to know the role of 立ち in the sentence. Is it works as an infinitive verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 立ち is the masu-stem of 立つ used as 中止法. It's a bookish or more formal way of continuing a sentence used instead of a te-form.

- [て versus combining-form for joining clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23789/5010)
- [Removal of て in Japanese novels](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70321/5010)
- [なく vs. なくて and stem form vs. てform as conjunctions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2934/5010)
- [Is there a term for using conjugating verbs such that the sentence continues with another clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/5010)

> 黒田君達特Sが上に立ち、望月君達がそれを下から支える役回りというわけなんです。
> = 黒田君達特Sが上に**立って**、望月君達がそれを下から支える役回りというわけなんです。
>
> Kuroda and other members of the 特S (Team) will stand at the top, and Mochizuki and his team will play a role of supporting them from below.

This 上 ("high position") refers to either a physically high position (e.g., roof) or a socially high position (leader/commander). See the previous context.

Comment: Thank you very much